# Shutting down a WPF application from App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, application-shutdown

I am currently writing a WPF application which does command-line argument handling in App.xaml.cs (which is necessary because the Startup event seems to be the recommended way of getting at those arguments). Based on the arguments I want to exit the program at that point already which, as far as I know, should be done in WPF with `Application.Current.Shutdown()` or in this case (as I am in the current application object) probably also just `this.Shutdown()`.

The only problem is that this doesn't seem to work right. I've stepped through with the debugger and code after the `Shutdown()` line still gets executed which leads to errors afterwards in the method, since I expected the application not to live that long. Also the main window (declared in the StartupUri attribute in XAML) still gets loaded.

I've checked the documentation of that method and found nothing in the remarks that tell me that I shouldn't use it during `Application.Startup` or `Application` at all.

So, what is the right way to exit the program at that point, i. e. the `Startup` event handler in an `Application` object?

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? Please update your question.

Comment: Click [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6602102/2342414) for a simple and working answer

Answer (score 61, accepted):

First remove the StartupUri property from App.xaml and then use the following:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        bool doShutDown = ...;

        if (doShutDown)
        {
            Shutdown(1);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            this.StartupUri = new Uri("Window1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work right :(
Specifically I'm getting NullReferenceExceptions in the main window's constructor, which may be easily circumvented. But as far as I understand it shutting down the application should work without instantiating the window referenced by StartupUri.

Comment: I changed my answer to show you how you can avoid your main window to be created. It is important that you first remove the StartupUri from App.xaml.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. But I find it kinda unintuitive that the StartupUri is always loaded regardless whether the application should already have exited.

Comment: This doesn't work if you are trying to shut down from `InitApplication()`, as in my case. Even if `StartupUri` is null, which it already is in my case because I have no main window, `this.Shutdown()` has no effect.

Comment: `InitApplication()` is executed before `OnStartup()`, so I have to set a boolean during `InitApplication()`, then call `return`, and check for the boolean in `OnStartup()` and then exit as above.

Comment: When I do this, the program exits but the console window doesn't redraw the console.  weird.

Answer (score 9):

If you remove the StartupUri from app.xaml for an application with a MainWindow you need to make sure you make the following call in your OnStartup method otherwise the application will not terminate when your MainWindow closes.

```
this.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
```

@Frank Schwieterman, something along these lines may help you with your console window issue.

Comment: This page details the WPF startup and shutdown procedures very clearly... http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFStartupShutdown.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I did this a little differently to avoid having to set the `StartupUri` and `ShutdownMode` properties. First edit the `App.xaml` file and replace `StartupUri` with `Startup`:

```
<Application x:Class="Menu.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Menu"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then add `Application_Startup` to the code along with `OnExit`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private volatile static Mutex s_mutex;

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        s_mutex = new Mutex(true, @"Global\MenuMutex", out bool grantedOwnership);

        if (!grantedOwnership)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Another instance is already running!", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            Current.Shutdown();
        }
        else
            new MainWindow().Show();
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        s_mutex?.ReleaseMutex();
        s_mutex?.Dispose();
        s_mutex = null;
        base.OnExit(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write in the Application_Startup:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)  
{  
    ...
    if (!condition)  
    {  
        e.GetType()  
          .GetProperty("PerformDefaultAction", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)  
          .SetValue(e, false);  
        Shutdown();  
        return;  
    }  
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).